# Python - Randomize order of functions python

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a code by which there is a number of functions which are the steps of presenting them on a screen later on. Is there a way to randomize **which group starts first but then all the consecutive steps are randomized respectively**? To give you some more context:

We have two groups (A & B) and each group consists of several functions (imagine them as steps of a game). As you can see we start with step 1 of group A, then moving on to step 1 of group B and so on. :

```
for i in range(x):
     functionA1():
     functionB1():
     functionA2():
     functionB2():
....
```

So the idea is that the game starts and the **steps are alternating between group A & B.**
Is there a way to have randomly either group A or group B starting and then the consecutive steps are also changing? So this is one option (the one above) and the other option, randomly selected, would be:

```
for i in range(x):
     functionB1():
     functionA1():
     functionB2():
     functionA2():
....
```

Since the list of functions is quite extensive, I really want to avoid to just write down in the code the two possible options.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So only the starting group is randomised, and then based on that the sequence is alternating? Say if you have 3 groups A, B, C and a random start at B then would expected the sequence be B1, C1, A1, B2, C2, .... ?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is exactly what I expect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is something like:

```
def functionA1():
    print('A1')
def functionA2():
    print('A2')
def functionA3():
    print('A3')
def functionB1():
    print('B1')
def functionB2():
    print('B2')
def functionB3():
    print('B3')

groupA = (functionA1, functionA2, functionA3)
groupB = (functionB1, functionB2, functionB3)
groups = [groupA, groupB]
import random
random.shuffle(groups)
for function1, function2 in zip(*groups):
    function1()
    function2()
```

output

```
B1
A1
B2
A2
B3
A3
```

In addition - if there are more than 2 groups, it may be better to do something like this:

```
for functions in zip(*groups):
    for my_function in functions:
        my_function()
```

This way it will be easy to extend it with large number of groups without need to change that part of the code.

Comment: This seems like it does not go over the steps alternating between the groups. So indeed it shuffles the groups but then it goes through the all  steps for groupA and then for all the steps of groupB. It should be one step  for groupA, then for groupB, then again groupA and so on..

Comment: That's not correct. I added sample functions and sample output. There is `zip(*groups)` that will consequently combine one function from the first group and one from the second (after groups being shuffled).

Answer (score 0):

To keep order of levels you can to shuffle them separately.

You can treat functions as first class citizens .

```py
import random

lst = [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", 'b2']]

for el in lst:
    random.shuffle(el)
print(ch)
```

example output:

```
[['a1', 'b1'], ['b2', 'a2']]
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I understand that, but this wouldn't be correct in my case. Expected output should be  `[['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2']]` or `[['b1', 'a1'], ['b2', 'a2']]` so the steps are alternating respectively

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from random import shuffle

functions = ([functionA1, functionB1], [functionA2, functionB2])
for i in range(x):
     for group in functions:
         shuffle(group)
         for func in group:
             func()
```

Comment: `x` is not defined (nor is clear what the purpose of the loop is anyway) and also each group will be shuffled separately, which is not consistent with OP requirements . I don't know why @labgeek switch to accept this answer

Comment: You are actually completely right. It just didn't happen to notice it. But I just ran the full code and I started noticing that something was wrong in the code. Thanks for noticing, I am still a beginner so I couldn't spot the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have many functions, it's better to organize them somehow. For example in separate modules:

```
# file group_a.py
def function1():
    print("A1")
```

```
# file group_b.by
def function1():
    print("B1")
```

```
# file main.py
import group_a
import group_b
import random

first, second = random.sample((group_a, group_b), k=2)

for i in range(1, x):
    getattr(first, f"function{i}")()
    getattr(second, f"function{i}")()
```

If your naming scheme of the function is like this, you can use `getattr` to find the correct function.

If they had arbitrary names, you would need to create a list in each module with the functions in the correct order. This would then be similar to buran's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following can is extendable to any number of groups and functions.  Will illustrate for three groups.

```
from random import randrange

def rotate(arr, r):
    '  Roates an array '
    return arr[r:] + arr[:r]

# Generate groups of functions
n = 4  # number of functions in a group
groupA = [lambda i = i: f'A{i}' for i in range(1, n+1)]
groupB = [lambda i = i: f'B{i}' for i in range(1, n+1)]
groupC = [lambda i = i: f'C{i}' for i in range(1, n+1)]


# Random starting index (i.e. 0 to n-1)
index = randrange(0, n)

# Create function selections (rotate based upon index)
selection = [rotate(x, index) for x in zip(groupA, groupB, groupC)]
for funcs in selection:
    for f in funcs:
        print(f())
```

**Output**

Ex 1:

```
B1
C1
A1
B2
C2
A2
B3
C3
A3
B4
C4
A4
```

Ex. 2

```
A1
B1
C1
A2
B2
C2
A3
B3
C3
A4
B4
C4
```